# I got a Routing error when using form_tag in rails 3.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I am new to rails. Today I encountered a problem that I have no clue how to fix it.
Basically I am trying to put a input area and a submit button on one webpage, and the input values is stored in the params[:name], passing to the export_issues method defined in issues controller.
this is what the view file looks like

```
    <%= form_tag(:controller => 'issues', :action => 'export_issues') do%>
    <p>
    <%= label_tag :name, "name:" %>
    <%= text_field_tag :name, params[:name]%>
    </p>
    <%= submit_tag "Submit"  %>
```

when i click the 'Submit' I got "Routing error". But if I just press F5 refresh the error pageor type 127.0.0.1/issues/export_issues it will work just as I wanted

and this is the code related to issues controller in routes.rb

```
resources :issues, :only => [:index, :destroy] do
  member do
    post 'create_comment'
    get 'mark_readed'
end
collection do
  get 'export_issues'
  delete 'destroy_comment'
end
end
```

basically what the export_issues does is to read the database and export data to a CSV file.
It worked fine without the form_tag codes taking part in.

So what is the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is simple. By default `form_tag` creates form element with `method=post`. Like:

```
form_tag('/myposts')
```

will create form tag as follows:

```
<form action="/myposts" method="post">
```

However, our routing says, it accepts only `get`. So, the form opening tag should be:

```
<%= form_tag(:controller => 'issues', :action => 'export_issues', :method => :get) do%>
```

For more information, please consult the [apidocs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag).

Comment: Thanks for a fast and precise answer